# Imposible editar registros cuyo ID sea mayor a 9: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Tags: python, mysql, flask

**CONTEXTO**. Windows 10, Python 3.9.1, Flask 2.0.1 y MySQL 5.7.24.

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER**. Un CRUD con Python, Flask y MySQL.

**PROBLEMA**. Listo en el navegador todos los registros de una tabla de la BD, y a cada fila le pongo un link para editarlo. Cuando doy clic a *editar* soy redirigido a una nueva vista que muestra un formulario para editar el registro. Todo funciona bien siempre y cuando los IDs de los registros tengan un único dígito (1-9). Pero si intento editar un registro cuyo ID tiene dos dígitos (del 10 en adelante), salta este error: ***MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting***.

**ESTO ES LO QUE ESTOY HACIENDO**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'db'
mysql = MySQL(app)

app.secret_key = "mysecretkey"

@app.route('/')
def Index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return render_template('index.html', contacts=data)

@app.route('/edit/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_contact(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = %s', (id))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return render_template('edit-contact.html', contact=data[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

**CÓMO HE INTENTADO SOLUCIONAR EL PROBLEMA**

Googleando, encuentro que este problema está relacionado con el modo en que se arma la query dentro del *cur.execute*. He intentado estas variantes, sin éxito:

1. `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = %s', (id))`
2. `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = \'%s\'', (id))`
3. `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM` contacts`WHERE`id `= %s', (id))`
4. `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM` contacts`WHERE`id `= %s", (id))`
5. `cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = %s""", (id))`
6. `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '"+id+"'")`
7. También intenté convertir el ID a str: `id = str(id)`

Ayuda, por favor! Saludos!

Comment: 1. Intenta hacer un print de lo que obtienes de la url 2. Haz probado con los *f-strings*?

Comment: @Christian, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. ¡Funcionó lo de los f-strings! Si quieres postea tu sugerencia como respuesta para así darte el crédito. La cosa terminó funcionando con este cambio: cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = {id}")

Comment: así estoy bien, no te preocupes :), tu también puedes publicar la respuesta. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El compañero @Christian hizo un comentario sugiriendo el uso de los **f-strings**. Al buscar qué son los f-strings me entero que el código porcentaje (`%s`) utilizado para armar queries no es muy bueno que digamos, y que lo mejor es utilizar otras alternativas, como, precisamente, los f-strings. Así que modifiqué la query, de esto:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = %s', (id))
```

A esto:

```
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = {id}")
```

Y finalmente el error mencionado desapareció.

**¡Gracias!**